# How do I call a static method on elements of List<Class<? extends ClassName>>?

Tags: java, generics

I have several classes derived from same base class which has a static method.
I want to call this static method in a loop per each derived class type univeserally.
I use a collection ArrayList<Class<? extends MyBaseClass>> and I want Java to trust that each of the list elements must have the static method, because I clearly say that all they are "? extends MyBaseClass".

```
    ArrayList<Class<? extends MyBaseClass>> TYPES = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(
            MyDerivedClass_1.class,  MyDerivedClass_2.class,  MyDerivedClass_3.class)
    );
    for(Class<? extends MyBaseClass> type :  TYPES) {
        type.myStaticMethod();
    }
```

This does not work unfortunately. Java treats the "type" as just a Class, not as Class<? extends MyBaseClass>.

If I do absolutely the same with concrete instances of derived classes then it works:

```
    ArrayList<? extends MyBaseClass> derivatives = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(
            new MyDerivedClass(), new MyDerivedClass_2(), new MyDerivedClass_3())
    );
    for(MyBaseClass d: derivatives) {
        d.myStaticMethod();
    }
```

But I cannot use this way, because at that moment the derived classes (they are singletons) may be not instantiated yet in my program.

The method myStaticMethod() is actually the *getInstance*() method in my program which can return an instance or null depending on whether it was already instantiated.

Is there any way to achieve what I want in Java?

Comment: `Class` is for reflection, so using `Class#getDeclaredMethods` in conjunction with passing `null` for the object parameters is how you would reflectively call a static method.

Comment: You have to call the method either via [reflection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html) or by using [method handles](https://www.baeldung.com/java-method-handles)

Comment: Your approach is wrong. You cannot be sure to have the static method in your class by inheriting from a parent class which has the said static factory method. You can always create a child class without an own version of that static method - and what instance would you expect to have created then?